# Maximum variation of constraint in a linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Ok so we have the following linear problem:

$\max10x_1+10x_2+9x_3$

$s.t$

$2x_1+3x_2+4x_3\le24 $

$3x_1+4x_2+5x_3\le33 $

$x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0 $

By using simplex i can easily find that the optimal solution is $x_1=11, x_2=x_3=0.$ .My question is this. Suppose 33,24 are our resources for producing products. **Ηow much can we increase or decrease 33 and keep our solution optimal???** The example is to make me understand this more easily, i am looking for a general way to examine how much we can change a constraint in a linear program while our solution stays optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general approach.

Solve the original (a.k.a. baseline) problem, producing optimal solution $x^*$, with corresponding optimal objective value $V^*$

Now pick a single inequality ( $\le$ )constraint, with all terms involving the variables on the left-hand side.

If this inequality is satisfied with equality at $x*$, no decrease of the right-hand side value is possible without making $x^*$ infeasible, and therefore non-optimal (but see next paragraph).  If it is not satisfied with equality at $x*$, the right-hand side value can be decreased without making $x^*$ non-optimal down to the value the left-hand side attains for $x^*$.

If this inequality is satisfied with equality at $x*$, you can find out down to what right-hand side value the optimal objective value, $V^*$, can be maintained (but with a different optimal x) by solving another Linear Programming problem.  Specifically, the new problem is the same as the original problem, except that the objective function is changed to minimize $R$, the inequality constraint in question is changed to have right-side of$R$, and another constraint is added: original objective function $ = V^*$ (in your example, $10x_1 + 10x_2 + 9x_3 = V^*$).  The optimal value of R returned by the program is the minimal value of right-hand side for the inequality constraint in your original problem such that the optimal objective value is unchanged.

The maximum right-hand side value for the specified inequality constraint for which the solution $x^*$ remains optimal can be handled in a similar manner. Note that if the right-hand side value is increased, $x^*$ can never become infeasible, so it's just a question of at what point a better solution becomes optimal.  Therefore, solve a new problem, exactly as described in the previous problem, except that the added constraint is: original objective function $\ge V^* + \text{tol}$, where $\text{tol}$ is some minimum amount by which the optimal objective value must improve, and must be greater than solver constraint tolerance; so $\text{tol}$ of say, 1e-4. If this new problem is infeasible, then $x^*$ remains optimal (within objective value tolerance of $\text{tol}$) for the original problem, no matter how much the right-hand side value of the inequality constraint is increased.

In your particular example, solving the problems in the two preceding paragraphs shows that if the right-hand side value of 33 is decreased at all, the optimal objective value decreases, and if it is increased at all, the optimal objective value increases.

Answer (score 0):

If we rewrite this example like this:
$2x_1+3x_2+4x_3≤a_1$
$3x_1+4x_2+5x_3≤a_2$
Then $x_1=\min([\frac{a_1}{2}], [\frac{a_2}{3}]), x_2,x_3=0$ will be optimal. So if you increase/decrease your $a_1$ or $a_2$ so that the minimum changes the optimal solution will shift. Note that sometimes there is more than one optimal solution.